# Visiting Schengen Countries with Type D Visa

Tags: schengen, germany, netherlands, long-stay-visas

I have been issued a Type D Visa for studying in the Netherlands. 
I know I can travel in schengen countries with this Visa, but can I enter any country before visiting Netherlands?

I am planning to reach University of Twente, Enschede through Germany.

Delhi -> Frankfurt -> Munster -> Enschede(by Bus)

This is a much shorter route instead of going through Amsterdam. My concern is would I be allowed in immigration in Germany before I have entered Netherlands?

Comment: The distance from Frankfurt to Enschede is more than twice as great as the distance from Amsterdam to Enschede.  How is this shorter than going through Amsterdam?

Comment: I'll be taking a flight from Frankfurt to Munster

Comment: Aha, that makes much more sense :)

Answer (score 4):

Yes. The D visa allows you travel through any Schengen state on the way to your destination, and also to visit them **as if** you had a multiple-entry C visa with the same validity period.

That means you can spend up to 90 out of every 180 days in Schengen states other than the one which gave you a D visa, with the usual restrictions for a short-stay visa (no right to work, even if your D visa includes a work permit).